# How can I remove the spacing on the right-side?

Tags: html, css, spacing

I'm coding this site [http://www.allrecht.nl/new](http://allrecht.nl/new/) , and running into the following issue: on the right side of the entire site is a space of about 40px - i cant figure out where its coming from .. can anyone help me with this?

It happended after i changed the width and margin of the #pricing and #container (so the table would be centered in the middle of the DIV). I've tried to adjust the body padding/margin but that doesnt do the trick. I didnt try to reverse the margin/width i adjusted on both DIV's bc i need them to be centered - so if you guys have a solution so the pricing table is still centered and also there is no spacing on the right side of the website, i'd love to hear it :D

Comment: What 40px on the right? That site you posted looks centered and even to me...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add     `box-sizing: border-box;` to your #footer in css. You should use that as a global rule, so the blocks are not affected by padding. Use this link for explanation and examples! http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Also as a regard, the div's you use should remain as display:block, display: inline-block will add a small padding top and right.(Ex: your grey line bellow footer)

Answer (score 0):

thank you Dinca!! I also added a ';' after the padding in the #footer - together it works now :) Thanks a lot!